# OSX 10.6.8 internal mic does not register voice in PhotoBooth but registers in system preferences

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, microphone

I am having issues where so far PhotoBooth video recordings and flash based web applications do not register my voice using the internal mic.

I have also tried with and without plugging in headphones (no mic on head phones).

***System Preferences -> Sound -> Input*** however does register my voice as well as ***System Preferences -> Speech -> Speech Recognition -> Calibrate***

[image: System Preferences]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a stupid question but it just caught me when I was looking into your problem. Are you sure you have output set to `Internal Speakers` not something else like an Airplay device?

When you set the "Sound Effect" do you get noise out of the speakers